# Node JS upload a video to my youtube account

Tags: node.js, youtube

I found this source but I couldn't upload a video to my youtube account and dev.google's documentation is old and unclear (at least in my opinion) How can I add video at least a source would have been great
Mostly I have OAuth2 problems
'I cant Authenticate with OAuth couldn't find clear documentation or clear example'
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

````
const path = require("path");
const readline = require("readline");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { authenticate } = require("@google-cloud/local-auth");

// initialize the Youtube API library
const youtube = google.youtube("v3");

// very basic example of uploading a video to youtube
async function runSample(fileName) {
  // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
  const auth = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, "../youtube-upload/oauth2.keys.json"),
    scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
    ],
  });
  google.options({ auth });

  const fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
  const res = await youtube.videos.insert(
    {
      part: "id,snippet,status",
      notifySubscribers: false,
      requestBody: {
        snippet: {
          title: "Node.js YouTube Upload Test",
          description: "Testing YouTube upload via Google APIs Node.js Client",
        },
        status: {
          privacyStatus: "private",
        },
      },
      media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(fileName),
      },
    },
    {
      // Use the `onUploadProgress` event from Axios to track the
      // number of bytes uploaded to this point.
      onUploadProgress: (evt) => {
        const progress = (evt.bytesRead / fileSize) * 100;
        readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
        readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
        process.stdout.write(`${Math.round(progress)}% complete`);
      },
    }
  );
  console.log("\n\n");
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  const fileName = process.argv[2];
  runSample(fileName).catch(console.error);
}

module.exports = runSample; ```
````

Comment: _"Mostly I have OAuth2 problems"_ Can you update your question with details on these problems?

Comment: thx for advice I edited